# Pandas create a new dataframe by returning the rows matching strings from a list checked against cells in 1 column from an another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, string-matching

I have created a dataframe from a .csv with just over 3.8 million rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

file_name = 'bigfile.csv'
bigfile_df = pd.read_csv (file_name, low_memory=False)
```

I am then importing a second csv which I would like to be my list:

```
input_df = pd.read_csv('list.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Then converting this to a List:

```
l = input_df['Column_Name'].tolist()
```

Which when printed looks like:

```
['Text Text Text', 'Text Text Text', 'Text Text Text']
```

The list is fairly large as well containing over 12,000 rows and contains strings.

What I would like to do is take each entry within the list and check for any matches within cells from a column ['Name'] in the bigfile_df and create a new dataframe with the entire row of these matches.

I hope this all makes sense, I have looked for similar examples to try and answer this but could not find. Thank you in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the query method:

```py
output_dfs = []
for entry in l:
    output_dfs.append(bigfile_df.query('Name == @entry')
```

Edit: I may have misunderstood, if you want one dataframe you can do as follows:

```py
output_df = bigfile_df.query('Name in @l')
```

This will search all rows of `bigfile_df` for rows which have the 'Name' column value appearing in your list `l`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I am getting an error when I the above:

-----------------------------------------------------------------
UndefinedVariableError: name 'Name' is not defined


​

Comment: Replace `'Name'` with whatever your column name is, the way that pandas query works can be explored in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

Comment: Sorry ignore me, came in with a fresh head and realised the line where I was renaming the column to "Name" was just df not bigfile_df so was actually renaming, well nothing! That worked perfectly, thank you VERY much.